# How can I use named pipes to stream a GCP Cloud Storage object to an executable that wants input files?

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage, named-pipes

I have a third-party executable that takes a directory path as an argument and in turn looks there for a collection of .db files. I have said collection of files stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and would like to stream the content of those files into some local named pipes that can be used as input to the executable.

I'm writing an application to perform the above in Go and am using the `"cloud.google.com/go/storage"` package to work with cloud storage objects.

As a note, I need all pipes/files to be available for reading at the time I run the executable.

What is the best way to go about this? I'm looking to essentially used the named pipe as a proxy of sorts to make remote files look local to this executable. Possible?

Comment: Can you using gsutil to pipe? gsutil cat command can print multiple objects to stdout.

Comment: I'll investigate this option. I'm not entirely sure off the bat.

Comment: Were you able to test that last bit? @TylerMace